# Storing a case insensitive varchar in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, collation, case-insensitive

I want to add some constraint to my username *varchar* in the SQL table so that if a username exists, a duplicate username in a different case cannot be created. How can I do this? Thanks

Edit:
I am using PostgreSQL, a little syntax help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createindex.html)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX lower_title_idx ON films ((lower(title)));
```

Comment: Do you need to add a constraint to the table after this?  I tried to do: `ALTER TABLE films ADD CONSTRAINT unique_file_title UNIQUE USING INDEX lower_title_idx;` but got error `Cannot create a primary key or unique constraint using such an index. Index contains expressions.`   I tried inserting case-insensitive data and it seems to work even without the constraint.

Answer (score 5):

Do note that PostgreSQL 8.4 (currently beta) will have a [case-insensitive text type](http://docs.postgresql.fr/8.4/citext.html).

Comment: Have to run `CREATE EXTENSION citext;` statement once on every new database

Answer (score 4):

If the tables are not yet populated you may consider simply converting to a standard upper or lower case prior to doing any insertions and making the field a primary key (or just have a unique constraint).  If the user want to see his userid in the case he specified this could be another column in the database.

**Update**:Based on the updated tags I would still suggest the solution I have proposed as being less dependent on a particular DBMS.

Comment: -1 sorry. Only badness could arise out of storing a username in two different ways when one of them can be trivially computed from the other. There's no need to break normalisation here as Endlessdeath's answer shows.